# Hosting Django on a private server

Tags: django, hosting, web-hosting, vps

I have been provided with a private server space in a an organisation to host a django application I have been working on.

I have the public IP, username, password and ssh port. There is no cpanel.

How can i host the project and make it appear in the internet with the domain name not the public IP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a domain name that points at that IP if you want your application to show up with a domain name and not an IP.

Second :

1/ You need to download a ssh client like [PuTTy](https://www.putty.org/) and FTP client like [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/). (you only need filezilla if you dont have a github repository of your project that you can clone)

2/ Launch Filezilla. Enter your IP and whatever filezilla requires to log you in.

3/ Copy your project folder into the server. (browse it in the left side, drag and drop it in the right side.

*** Checkpoint : now we have your code on the server ***

4/ Login with your IP to Putty. A console will appear (Im supposing that your server is a linux machine) : enter your username then password.

5/ From here I'll have [The official Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/) take it. It is detailed and easy to follow to configure WSGI and Apache.

I wish you good luck.